# Extract audio from a MPEG(.ts) file in memory in python, Without writing MPEG to a file

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg, mpeg

I am working on a project that need to extarct audio from a stream which is transmitted by .ts(MPEG-2 Transport Stream) file.

Currently I need to First save the file to file system, Then open it using [moivepy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy) to convert to WAV format audio.

The streaming requires realtime transmit, and there are multiple .ts file need to be process every second, Moivepy is too slow to open them all and convert each in realtime.

So I wonder if I can finish the whole process of extracting audio from MPEG in memory, avioding file system IO may speed up the process. How can I do it?

Comment: _So I wonder if I can finish the whole process of extracting audio from MPEG in memory, avioding file system IO may speed up the process._ You probably can, yes. _How can I do it?_ That's off topic, Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials, or documentation, nor is it a free code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly try the [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) package where you can take a look at the `-target` flag in the output function and specify `.wav` file output. https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis. Most flags in the synopsis page are offered in the package. I haven't yet encountered one that is not offered.

[python-ffmpeg python bindings documentation](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/)

Example code:

```py
import ffmpeg

audio_input = ffmpeg.input(url)
audio_output = ffmpeg.output(audio_input, save_location, target='filename.wav')
audio_output.run()
```